# Why cant python gui modules handle while true loops is it a python problem or a module problem?

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

Whilst creating a project in python, I wanted to create a GUI, so I decided, to use the module tkinter. After trying to implement a while True loop in my code, it seems the GUI had frozen and was unusable, so I am here to ask is this a problem with the GUI modules themselves, or is it a problem with Python itself? Is this the same in other languages?

Comment: If a loop never ends a program hangs. That's the same in all languages. The normal GUI program runs in loops, checking for user input at each iteration. If you do not check for input, the program becomes inresponsive and "frozen"

Comment: In other words, it's a "you" problem 

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of most GUI frameworks. For a GUI to work, it must be able to receive a steady flow of events to be processed. These events can be button clicks, typing on a keyboard, and system-generated events where the OS tells the window it needs to be refreshed.

The code that processes these events is typically called the event loop - it is a global loop that waits for events, compares them to registered handlers, and then calls the handlers. In tkinter, calling the `mainloop` function starts this event loop.

When you put a long or infinite loop in the same thread that the GUI is operating, while that code is running the GUI framework is unable to process these events. Thus, the GUI appears to be frozen because it can't refresh itself.

Some toolkits might run the event loop in a separate thread. That is not the case with tkinter, and maybe other python-based GUI frameworks. With tkinter, on some platforms it's best to run the event loop in the same thread that created the widgets. On OSX, this is a strict requirement.

If you need to create your own loops in a GUI program, or any long running function, it's best that you create a separate thread for any such code.